# How to replace each occurrence of a string with an incrementing counter in vim?

Tags: vim

I have 203 instances of the word `ubuntu` in a file, and I want to replace each one with `UBUNTU_X`, where "X" is an incrementing counter. In other words, the original file is:

```
ubuntu xxxxxxxx ubuntu xxxxxxxx ubuntu xxxubuntuxxx xxxubuntu ubuntuxxxxxx ...
```

And I want to replace it with:

```
UBUNTU_1 xxxxxxxx UBUNTU_2 xxxxxxxx UBUNTU_3 xxxUBUNTU_4xxx xxxUBUNTU_5 UBUNTU_6xxxxx ...
```

The last occurrence must be `UBUNTU_203`

Comment: It seems perfectly clear to me as it stands now.  I have an answer all written for it, also, which I'll post as soon as it's taken off hold.

Comment: @Wildcard Open now

Answer (score 2):

`ggOUbuntu_0`<kbd>Esc</kbd>`0"ndeddqq/\<Ubuntu\>^Mde"nP^Ab"nyeq999@q`

This should do what you want if typed in in normal mode.

Explanation:

- `gg` - go to first line of file
- `O` - create a new line above the current line and enter insert mode
- `Ubuntu_0` - typing text
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> - exit insert mode, can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>
- `0` - go to start of current line
- `"nde` - into register n, delete to the end of the word
- `dd` - delete current line
- `qq` - begin recording macro into register q
- `/\<Ubuntu\>^M` - search for Ubuntu.  \< and \> mean word boundaries, and Ctrl-M is the same as pressing Enter.
- `de` - delete to end of word
- `"nP` - put the contents of register n before the cursor position
- `^A` - Ctrl-A, increment the number under the cursor by one
- `b` - go to start of current word
- `"nye` - into register n yank text to the end of current word
- `q` - stop recording macro
- `999@q` - run macro recorded in register q 999 times (or stop when the pattern `\<Ubuntu\>` isn't found anymore)

This can be modified slightly depending on your exact requirements.  For instance, I assumed that you only want to match "Ubuntu" as a whole word.  I also assume that you only want to match the given capitalization—or, if you have ignorecase on, that you don't mind the various capitalizations of "ubuntu" all being transformed to "Ubuntu".

Answer (score 1):

Several linux distributions have vim compiled with Perl support . If this is the case, you have a `:perldo command` and a `:perl command`

```
:perldo  s/ubuntu/"UBUNTU" . ++$a/ge
```